# time estimation for badblocks completion

Tags: badblocks

I recently was trying badblocks and tried- the following thing -

```
$ sudo badblocks -v  -s /dev/sda8
Checking blocks 0 to 1300928511
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): ^C7.81% done, 12:38 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)

Interrupted at block 101550528
```

Is there a way to get total time estimation of a partition ?

Comment: Have you tried to calculate an estimation from the percentage of completion and the time elapsed?

Comment: badblocks only gives the message you've already shown. So: no, not unless you implement it yourself. Note that those ETAs are always off by a great margin (HDDs don't have uniform speed across their surface).

Comment: I know that there is difference in speeds at the center of a traditional spinning disk and at the edges.